# value recorded in the database differs from the value of the variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save a file in php, and the name of the file is being changed using the date, time and a random number. The same name of the file is being recorded in a database, however the name of the record in the database differs always of a few digits from the one being generated and used for the file upload. It looks like when the operation of uploading of the file occurs, the random number is being regenerated...:( but a that should be happening.

```
<?php
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);

include 'conn.php';

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$today = date('y-m-j');
$time1 = date('H-i', time()); // 12:50:29

$temp = mt_rand ( 0 , 200 );

$newfilename = $today.'_'.$temp.'_'.$time1.'.zip'; //generates a random name based on time for the 

$DBnewfilename="http://localhost/purchasesystem/uploads/".$newfilename;


$sql = "update PURCHASE_REQUESTS set URL='$DBnewfilename' where id=$id";         

$result = @mysql_query($sql);



    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$newfilename)){

            echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

    } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
```

the database record URL is set as TEXT (however I have tried also varchar with no results) :(

thanks a lot for any advise you could possibly give me.
Kele

Comment: Please give an example of the actual filename and the one in the database.

Comment: sorry... 
this is the filename uploaded for example 15-10-29_164_15-26.zip

and this is the one in the database
15-10-29_196_15-26.zip

Comment: Try changing `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$newfilename)){` to `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], "uploads/".$newfilename)){`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, however that didn't work either :(

Comment: Hello! Are you sure this line is generating the string you think? $time1 = date('H-i', time()); // 12:50:29 .

Comment: Hello Eduardo, that part of the string is the same in both the filename uploaded as well as in the record of the database, what changes is that additional random number. It is generated only once but it is different from the filename and the record in the database..the rest is the same

Comment: There is nothing in your code sample that explains the behavior your seeing. We may need more context, but I'm not totally sure what. First I would put in some `echo`s or logging to inspect variables and see whats going on.

Comment: Actually just for the sake of "good practice", you should put your DB update inside the `if(move_uploaded_file...` you don't want to update your DB if the upload fails, right? Might fix your problem too.

Comment: yeah that is very weird, I have done so many echo and the number printed is the one used for the file, however only at the end the number in the record is being changed...for example I have tried to put a number generated based on the ms of the time, and that also changes. That is why I decided to place only minutes and seconds but still trying to add an additional random number...I am completely lost indeed :(

Comment: Dear dan08, you are correct, however when having the update at the end of the file, I had another weird problem, the record was blank. After searching here, I found out that one user could solve the issue by placing the update at the beginning of the file. I have no idea why that works but I decided to give it a try and felt into this other problem...but you are absolutely right that it should be done at the end

Comment: I tried to place back the update at the end and still different numbers, for example

15-10-29_136_15-54.zip in the database record
and 
15-10-29_170_15-54.zip as a file name  :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure your script is getting called multiple times somehow

Comment: it looks like only the random number is being re-generated..but echo even close to the upload operation gives the right filename number :(

Comment: All, thanks a lot for the support and prompt help, I have solved it. The mistake was with the id parameter that was not correct and was causing the strange behaviour with the update in the database. I have never seen a behaviour where only those two digits would be wrong...anyway solved.